# Retrieving a large 32 bit unsigned integer from a Bluetooth low energy GATT characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am attempting to retrieve a very large (potentially `2^32 - 1`) unsigned 32 bit integer from a bluetooth 4.0 characteristic using the [`getIntValue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getIntValue%28int,%20int%29) method of my [`BluetoothGattCharacteristic`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html) instance.

I am passing [`FORMAT_UINT32`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#FORMAT_UINT32) to [`getIntValue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getIntValue%28int,%20int%29), but because it returns an `Integer` it can't return a number larger than `2^31 - 1`.  When I try getting a value larger than `2^31 - 1` it incorrectly returns a negative integer.

What's the point of [`getIntValue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getIntValue%28int,%20int%29) accepting [`FORMAT_UINT32`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#FORMAT_UINT32) if it can't possibly return an unsigned 32 bit integer? Is there something I am missing?

Is my only option to use [`getValue()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getValue%28%29) and manually convert it to a `long`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this works for me:

```
long value = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32, 0) & 0x00000000ffffffffL;
```